# How to access this._id in map function in MongoDB MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing a MapReduce in Mongo to generate a reverse index of tokens for some documents. I am having trouble accessing document's _id in the map function.

Example document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4ea42a2c6fe22bf01f000d2d"),
        "attributes" : {
                "name" : "JCDR 50W38C",
                "upi-tokens" : [
                        "50w38c",
                        "jcdr"
                ]
        },
        "sku" : "143669259486830515"
}
```

(The field ttributes['upi-tokens'] is a list of text tokens I want to create reverse index for.)

Map function (source of the problem):

```
m = function () {
    this.attributes['upi-tokens'].forEach(
         function (token) { emit(token, {ids: [ this._id ]} ); }
    ); }
```

Reduce function:

```
r = function (key, values) {
    var results = new Array;
    for (v in values) {
        results = results.concat(v.ids);
    }
    return {ids:results};
}
```

MapReduce call:

```
db.offers.mapReduce(m, r, { out: "outcollection" } )
```

**PROBLEM** Resulting collection has **null** values everywhere where I'd expect an id instead of actual ObjectID strings.

Possible reason:

I was expecting the following 2 functions to be equivalent, but they aren't.

```
m1 = function (d) { print(d['_id']); }
m2 = function () { print(this['_id']); }
```

Now I run:

```
db.offers.find().forEach(m1)
db.offers.find().forEach(m2)
```

The difference is that m2 prints **undefined** for each document while m1 prints the ids as desired. I have no clue why.

Questions:

1. How do I get the _id of the current object in the **map** function for use in MapReduce? this._id or this['_id'] doesn't work.
2. Why exactly aren't **m1** and **m2** equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work... I made quite simple JS mistakes:

1. inner forEach() in the map function seems to overwrite 'this' object; this is no longer the main document (which has an _id) but the iterated object inside the loop)...
2. ...or it was simply because in JS the for..in loop only returns the keys, not values, i.e.

   for (v in values) {

now requires

```
values[v]
```

to access the actual array value. Duh...

**The way I circumvented mistake #1** is by using for..in loop instead of ...forEach() loop in the map function:

```
m = function () {
            for (t in this.attributes['upi-tokens']) {
                var token = this.attributes['upi-tokens'][t];
                emit (token, { ids: [ this._id ] });
            }
        }
```

That way "this" refers to what it needs to.

Could also do:

```
that = this;
this.attributes['upi-tokens'].forEach( function (d) { 
...
that._id...
...
}
```

probably would work just fine.

Hope this helps someone.